# How can I change the margins on a PDF document created by Doxygen?

Tags: pdf, latex, doxygen, margin, pdflatex

I am using doxygen to generate a PDF of my code documentation.  The PDF has very big margins when using `PAPER_TYPE = letter`.  It looks OK when using `a4wide` but I would like to have more control over it.  I want to use a package called geometry but can't figure out where to add code like this:

```
\usepackage[top=2.9cm,left=2in,bottom=1in,right=1in]{geometry}
```

I would like to not have to change the doxygen-generated tex files if possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `Doxyfile`, add or edit the `EXTRA_PACKAGES` line:

```
EXTRA_PACKAGES = mydoxy
```

Then create a new file called `mydoxy.sty`:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01]
\ProvidesPackage{mydoxy}[2009/12/29 v1.0.0 csmithmaui's Doxygen style]
\RequirePackage[top=2.9cm,left=2in,bottom=1in,right=1in]{geometry}
% any other custom stuff can go here
\endinput
```

Drop that `mydoxy.sty` where LaTeX can find it.

The `EXTRA_PACKAGES` line will tell Doxygen to add `\usepackage{mydoxy}` to the preamble of the `.tex` files it generates.  This will cause LaTeX to look for a file named `mydoxy.sty`.  In the `mydoxy.sty` file that we've created, we can add whatever LaTeX code we like (before the `\endinput` line).  Feel free to drop any other customizations you like in this style file.

Note that I haven't tested this, and I'm making a number of assumptions that may be false.  But it should at least get you started.